# How to calculate an an accumulated value conditionally?

Tags: python, pandas

This question is based on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75240753/how-to-calculate-an-an-accumulated-value-conditionally).

I have the following dataframe:

```
diff_hours   stage    sensor
0            0        20
0            0        21
0            0        21
1            0        22
5            0        21
0            0        22
0            1        20
7            1        23
0            1        24
0            3        25
0            3        28
6            0        21
0            0        22
```

I need to calculated an accumulated value of `diff_hours` while `stage` is growing. When stage drops to 0, the accumulated value `acc_hours` should restart to 0 even though `diff_hours` might not be equal to 0.

The proposed solution is this one:

```
blocks = df['stage'].diff().lt(0).cumsum()
df['acc_hours'] = df['diff_hours'].groupby(blocks).cumsum()
```

Output:

```
    diff_hours  stage  sensor  acc_hours
0            0      0      20          0
1            0      0      21          0
2            0      0      21          0
3            1      0      22          1
4            5      0      21          6
5            0      0      22          6
6            0      1      20          6
7            7      1      23         13
8            0      1      24         13
9            0      3      25         13
10           0      3      28         13
11           6      0      21          6
12           0      0      22          6
```

On the line 11 the value of `acc_hours` is equal to 6. I need it to be restarted to 0, because the `stage` dropped from `3` back to `0` in row 11.

The expected output:

```
    diff_hours  stage  sensor  acc_hours
0            0      0      20          0
1            0      0      21          0
2            0      0      21          0
3            1      0      22          1
4            5      0      21          6
5            0      0      22          6
6            0      1      20          6
7            7      1      23         13
8            0      1      24         13
9            0      3      25         13
10           0      3      28         13
11           6      0      21          0
12           0      0      22          0
```

How can I implement this logic?

Comment: `acc_hours` starts counting from 0 again, but you add the value 6 in the same line to it. IIUC you want to be the `cumsum()` shifted by one. Try to run it like this: `df['acc_hours'] = df['diff_hours'].shift(fill_value=0).groupby(blocks).cumsum()`

Comment: It gives me the same result.

Comment: I posted an answer to show my output.

Comment: Can you give the explicit expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expected output is unclear, what about a simple [`mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html)?

Masking only the value during the change:

```
m = df['stage'].diff().lt(0)
df['acc_hours'] = (df.groupby(m.cumsum())
                     ['diff_hours'].cumsum()
                     .mask(m, 0)
                  )
```

Output:

```
    diff_hours  stage  sensor  acc_hours
0            0      0      20          0
1            0      0      21          0
2            0      0      21          0
3            1      0      22          1
4            5      0      21          6
5            0      0      22          6
6            0      1      20          6
7            7      1      23         13
8            0      1      24         13
9            0      3      25         13
10           0      3      28         13
11           6      0      21          0
12           0      0      22          6
13           3      0      22          9
14           0      0      22          9
```

Or ignoring the value completely bu masking **before** groupby:

```
m = df['stage'].diff().lt(0)
df['acc_hours'] = (df['diff_hours'].mask(m, 0)
                     .groupby(m.cumsum())
                     .cumsum()
                  )
```

Output:

```
    diff_hours  stage  sensor  acc_hours
0            0      0      20          0
1            0      0      21          0
2            0      0      21          0
3            1      0      22          1
4            5      0      21          6
5            0      0      22          6
6            0      1      20          6
7            7      1      23         13
8            0      1      24         13
9            0      3      25         13
10           0      3      28         13
11           6      0      21          0
12           0      0      22          0
13           3      0      22          3
14           0      0      22          3
```

Comment: I've just posted the expected output. Sorry if it was unclear.

Comment: @Fluxy thanks, can you add 2 more rows with stage 0, the first one having an extra value in diff_hours?

Comment: Actually, I just did that in my examples, for clarity, let me know if this is what you want.

Comment: Could you please explain what mask and cumsum are doing in your code?

Comment: Sure, in `a.mask(b, c)`, `mask` replaces all values from `a` by values of `c` where `b` is `True`. `m.cumsum()` is a classical pandas way to generate groups with a new group every time there is a new `True`. I suggest you check the output of `df['diff_hours'].mask(m, 0)` and `m.cumsum()`.